# I want to create a file in npm but do not want append the file if it already exists

Tags: node.js, npm, fs

This is the code I am using :

```
var fs = require('fs');

function write_StyleSheet(path)
{   
var wStream = fs.createWriteStream(path, {flags: 'w'});
var mstrstyleStrt0="<!DOCTYPE html>\n <html>\n<head>\n<meta charset=\"utf-8\">\n<title>Test Summary</title>\n"; 
wStream.write(mstrstyleStrt0);
}
```

It is overwriting the file if it exists.
Can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this:

```
var wStream = fs.createWriteStream(path, {flags: 'w'});
```

to this:

```
var wStream = fs.createWriteStream(path, {flags: 'wx'});
```

if you don't want to write anything if the file exists. The "x" subspecifier forces the function to fail if the file exists, instead of overwriting it.

Be prepared to handle `error` events for the stream:

```
wStream.on('error', err => console.log('Error:', err.message));
```

because now you will get errors like:

```
Error: EEXIST: file already exists, open 'aaa.txt'
```

If, on the other hand, you want to append to the file if it exists, then change this:

```
var wStream = fs.createWriteStream(path, {flags: 'w'});
```

to this:

```
var wStream = fs.createWriteStream(path, {flags: 'a'});
```

See `open(2)` manpage for all the flags explanation:

- http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/open.2.html